# c# Value still null after assigning a value

Tags: c#

i don't know what i'm doing wrong, i'm working on an existing application and i'm creating a unit test for this method.

on the Test Method, i mocked the view and assigned a value on the item

```
_fakeView.Setup(x => x.Bag.Amount).Returns((decimal)300.32);
```

(Note that the Amount is string)

and i'm passing the view object to the presenter and initialized

```
_presenter = new Presenter(_fakeView.Object);
_presenter.InitializeForm();
```

and on the existing code for initialize, they have a line of code to reassign the values like this:

```
this._view.Amount = this._view.Bag.Amount.ToString();
```

when this line run, the this._view.Amount is still null even if this._view.Bag.Amount.ToString() has value.

i even tried setting it directly

```
this._view.Amount = "asdfgsdf"; but still null
```

please help

Comment: `this._view.Bag.Amount` is not null and still after `this._view.Amount = this._view.Bag.Amount.ToString();` , `this._view.Amount` is null ?

Comment: yes @Amit. that's why i don't understand what's wrong

Comment: if `this._view.Bag.Amount` is not null still you get `this._view.Amount` 
 null right after assignment , only one thing left here to see, `.ToString()` . I have never seen this method returns null. but still if `this._view.Bag.Amount` is string property, assign it directly, else first take `string str = this._view.Bag.Amount.ToString()` and see if str is null or what

Comment: `Amount` is a property, right? Although it is a good idea, there is no guarantee that a property's `get` will return what you `set`, other than convention. It depends on the code. Maybe you need to step through the code to see what is happening.

Comment: i even tried setting it directly this._view.Amount = "asdfgsdf"; but still null

Comment: @HVT_08 John Wu just said that there's no guarantee the `set` will actually `set` the value such that you can get it back from the `get`, if it's a property. I was assuming it to be a field.

Comment: @HVT_08 as John Wu suggested. you should be sure form your `Amount` property. is `get` is returning value directly and the same what you assign through `set` or there is some mistake or filter logic.

Comment: Have you used the debugger and immediate window to evaluate that expression and see what you're setting and step into the step call itself to make sure there's nothing funny there?

Comment: How is `_view` defined?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer, because it is an incomplete debugging request. I can think of 4 different reasons it MIGHT be failing (in code you didn't post) and I'm sure there are more: `Throwing` might be ignoring the excetpion at 'ToString' method, any one of custom methods (including  `Amount` itself if it is a property) reurning a null (would be easy to check with some break points), `ToString` having a custom implementation or `Amount` being a property with some form of validation that does not assign `"asdfgsdf"` or just resets it to null after spotting the failed validation.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you assign a value something, doesn't mean it can't be `null`. `this._view.Bag.Amount.ToString()` has to be returning null.

This means, either `this._view` is null, `this._view.Bag` is `null`, or `this._view.Bag.Amount` is `null`, or `ToString()` is failing somehow. You'll have to check the values and find out where the `null` is coming from.

Also, if `Amount` is `string` why are you using `ToString()`?

**Edit:** It is possible that the code for `Amount` is something like this:

```
// Get works as expected but set does literally nothing to change the backing field
private string amount = null;
public string Amount
{
    get => amount;
    set 
    {
         // Do literally nothing
    }
}
```

Or:

```
// Get will always return null, but set works as expected
prviate string amount;
public string Amount
{
    get => null;
    set => amount == value;
}
```

In both examples, `Amount` will always return `null` if you're trying to use only the `set`/`get`.

Is there a `SetAmount(string amount)` method you could call?

Comment: hi, it's the existing code, they said they don't want it to be changed to decimal. also, when i debugged and checked the this._view.Bag.Amount.ToString();, it did has value

Comment: We don't refer to variable names with the word "the." If you referred to me, you'd just call me "Austin" not "the Austin." Anyways, `this._view.Bag.Amount.ToString()` has a value that magically dissapears when it gets assigned? When do you check the value of `this._viewAmount?`

Comment: is it possible `this._view` or `this._view.Bag` to be null and for this `this._view.Amount = this._view.Bag.Amount.ToString();` and still it doesn't cause any exception!?

Comment: If the result from `ToString()` isn't `null` then it should not be possible. @HVT_08 You should post the code that follows because it must be something in how you're checking it.

Comment: @AustinWBryan, there are no code that follows on the method

Comment: Then how are you sure if it's even `null`?

Comment: The second one? Sure it will. It's setting the backing field the value that I specified, which is what I would expect. It's the `get` in that example that isn't behaving like we'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

i found what i'm missing..

```
_fakeView.SetupAllProperties();
```

i added this

```
_fakeView.SetupAllProperties();
```

before

```
_fakeView.Setup(x => x.Bag.Amount).Returns((decimal)300.32);
```